# Does MariaDB/MySQL cache key-value relations when joining across tables?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Let's assume we have a table users with columns (id, username, team_id).

We also have a teams table that has columns (id, name).

Let's assume we have a lot of users and team size often is big.

```
SELECT users.id, users.username, teams.name 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN teams ON users.team_id = teams.id;
```

Does the db engine cache associations like `team_id(14) = "Team Yellow"` or does it get the data from disk every single join (which I actually can't imagine)?

If caching is not applied here, it may be better to only fetch the users, then aggregate the team_ids and have a second query fetching the team data.

Edit: I am actually asking because it seems Laravel is exactly doing this here (3:37): https://youtu.be/bZlvzvGpCEE?t=217

Comment: A lot of storage-engine specific things happen inside; for eg: [InnoDB Buffer Pool](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html) ; or Query Cache (deprecated in latest versions now) ; or Adaptive Hash indexes etc. You will have to benchmark which one works best for you; either a `JOIN` or [Join Decomposition](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/high-performance-mysql/9780596101718/ch04.html)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya - That's Edition 2 of the book; it is quite old.  And virtually every argument they make for Join Decomposition is no longer relevant -- MyISAM is deprecated; QC is going away; multiple servers does not make sense; other caching is done in the buffer_pool.

Comment: @RickJames I have the 3rd edition and it still talks about Join Decomposition. I know QC is going away as mentioned in my previous comment. Anyways, what's your opinion about Join Decomposition; to me it makes  sense to use it as long as we are not having some filtering to be done , and the application developer is able to use the concept of object cache (some ORM call them entities)..So that same fields are not queried again and again in a single session.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya - Well, ORMs are not designed for scale; MySQL is.  When the data gets too big, you have to carefully say whether or not to pre-fetch stuff like that.  Another point about decomposition:  90% of a simple query is overhead.  That is, breaking the example into 2 selects will lead to about 1.9 times as much elapsed time (minus any savings).

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya - and the 3rd edition is getting old.

Comment: @RickJames I know it is getting outdated; but unfortunately, I have not been able to come across any other comprehensive book on MySQL, and authors of this book don't plan to have 4th edition any soon. I do go through MySQL official doc at times to compare/update stuff, and also short-notes on your website. If you know of any other comprehensive book/source, do let know. TIA :)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya - Sorry, I don't know of a "good book".  I pour some of my nearly-two-decades of experience into my web site, but mostly I pour my knowledge into this and other forums.  I have developed a keen understanding of how MySQL works; this gives me an important tool to answer questions.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya - Clearly (to me) the OP conjured up a plausible idea of how caching works.  But it is easy for me to say "no", even without testing or looking at code.  Also, I get a lot from Percona Live and Oracle Open World, which is coming up soon.

Answer (score 1):

In InnoDB, with its buffer_pool, the main "caching" is at the *block* level.  A block contains (typically) a hundred rows of data or index.

*Usually* a `JOIN` is done via "Nested Loop Join" (NLJ).  This means that the code starts reading one table (possibly using an index), then repeatedly reaches into the 'next' table.  The Optimizer looks at statistics (etc) to decide which table to start with.  See `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to see which order it picked.

In your simple example, starting with either table is about as good.  This assumes you have what is needed for indexing `ON users.team_id = teams.id`:  If going from users to teams, then `id` needs an index.  If going the other way, then `team_id` needs an index.

Somewhere in one of the blocks will happen to be `team_id(14) = "Team Yellow"`, but that is really irrelevant.

Another optimization that is sometimes used is BNL, Block Nested Lookup(?).  This is where the entire lookup needed for the second table is turned into a hash and held in memory for the lifetime of the query.

The "data" is kept in a B+Tree that is sorted by the `PRIMARY KEY`.  A secondary index looks essentially like the data BTree, except that the "data" is only the column(s) of the PK.

There are two ways to use a B+Tree:  drilling down to a specific value, or walking forward (or backward) to the 'next' item in index order.  Either or both are used a lot in the evaluation of a query.

That's about all there is.